# How to find out red pigment from capture image?

Tags: iphone

Please i m very thankful to all if u suggest me the answer as early as possible.

In my application I have to capture an image through mobile and then I have to find out  red pigment color status and skin tone color.

How it could be possible through coding in objective c.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question:

[iPhone, modify UIImage to a target average color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213668/iphone-modify-uiimage-to-a-target-average-color)

You can pretty much use the same technique to look at the pixel values of an image and then run your algorithm on it.